# Configuration system failed to initialize from c# com dll

Tags: c#, dll, com, vb6

I have com dll written in c# and everything works ok when I use it from the normal exe project in visual basic 6, but when I try to use it from the visual basic 6 dll then I get this error: configuration system failed to initialize. This is a dll, so it don't have any app.config file.

I get this error on this line:

```
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ApiUrl);
```

where ApiUrl is something like: https://www.api.com/

Anyone knows what can be wrong?

Edit:
Maybe there is something with permissions? The vb6 dll is called from the web service hosted on the iis on the same server.

Edit2:

It must be something with IIS_USER, because when I call the vb6 dll from normal exe project, then works.

Comment: It is not an error, just a warning.  Debug + Exceptions, untick the Thrown checkboxes.

Comment: I don't know .net, but I think I can't debug a dll, which is called from the vb6 dll

Answer (score 0):

The impression I get of your setup is:

You have a client (of some sort) that is connecting to a web service that is written in C#, that is calling a VB6 dll that in turn calls a COM-exposed C# dll?

When I've seen this error in the past, I've had multiple Configuration elements in the *.config file. You will have a *.config file for the main service, so I'd start looking there.

A quick google found this URL which backs what I've found in the past too: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b7603703-3805-4e73-ac6a-755a7c14e722/configuration-system-failed-to-initialize?forum=vbgeneral

(apologies for offering as an answer, I can't add comments due to having <50 rep)